# TCP Server only works in localhost scheme

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, tcp

I can establish a TCP connection between a TCP client and TCP server in localhost, however I can't repeat the same example for a connection with different computers into the same net range (sender Windows Server 2012 x64 R2 and receiver Windows 10 x64 Pro) . The TCP Server is a C# application and the TCP client is in node.js. I have disabled both Antivirus and Windows Firewall.

```
//SERVER C#

void Receive() {
        //tcp_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.62"), 212);
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
        tcp_Listener = new TcpListener(localAddr,212);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        tcp_Listener.Start();
        print("Server Start");

        while (mRunning)
        {
            // check if new connections are pending, if not, be nice and sleep 100ms
            if (!tcp_Listener.Pending()){
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            else {
                clientSocket = tcp_Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                if (dataFromClient != "") {
                    print ("Data from client: " + dataFromClient);
                } else {
                    print ("Client no data");
                }
                clientSocket.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
   //CLIENT NodeJS

        var net = require('net');

        var HOST = '192.168.0.136';
        var PORT = 212;

        var client = new net.Socket();
        client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

            console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
            // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client 
            client.write('MSG SENT!');

        });

        // Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
        // data is what the server sent to this socket
        client.on('data', function(data) {

            console.log('DATA: ' + data);
            // Close the client socket completely
            client.destroy();

        });

        // Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
        client.on('close', function() {
            console.log('Connection closed');
        });
```

The wireshark log about this whole connection is the following:

[image]

This is the log from  TCP Client:

[image]

Comment: Not related to your current problem but your server code is broken. `Read` returns *how many* bytes have been placed into your buffer and you need to make sure that you don't use parts of your buffer that don't in fact contain any received data.

Comment: Why do you have close **destroy** in both server and client directly? I think this will make problems, Especially the destroy in the  CallBack of the client .

Comment: @Bewar Salah I have removed the destroy of the client and the error persists

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the advise.

Comment: I didn't receive any debug error but using a "try catch" in the line `networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize)` I saw a integer overflow in this line. I have replaced for `networkStream.Read (bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length)`and the issue was solved. I don't know why it worked in localhost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced for networkStream.Read (bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length)